# Can I disable iTunes Connect crash reports in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports

Is it possible to add code and/or properties to an app that will **prevent** iOS from collecting crash reports? They should **not** be stored on the device or forwarded to Apple, regardless of user selection.

Comment: You could just make your app not crash ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you can't disable that feature.

the user can choose not to send them in the preferences but they are always recorded